# Why css is not getting applied to my web page?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have an asp.net form in which I am trying to apply some font settings to a textbox through css.This is what I have in my CSS:

```
body 
{

}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Lohit Devanagari',serif;  
    src: url('http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/lohitdevanagari.css');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

.txtQues
{
    font-family: 'Lohit Devanagari',serif;   
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:Yellow;
}
```

Below is a part of my page source where I have added the css to the page:

```
<head>
 <title>Question Master</title>
 <link href="../FontSettings.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <meta name="google-translate-customization" 
 content="3280487709591956-   dc3fc45d489f056a-g5378ebab0cbcd0a4-12"/>   
</head>
```

The TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server" Height="101px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="627px" meta:resourcekey="txtQuestionResource1"  EnableTheming="True" 
ontextchanged="txtQuestion_TextChanged" CssClass="txtQues"></asp:TextBox>
```

As soon as I apply the css to the form, I see a change in the color of the text box in the design window, which tells me that css is being applied,but when I run the code on the browser I find that neither the text box color changes nor the font.Kindly help me and let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Can we see the HTML for the element you are trying to style?

Comment: I assume the element you are trying to style ha sbeen given the class of `txtQues`?

Comment: Do you have correct path included for css?..link href="../FontSettings.css"?

Comment: View Source and make sure it is linking to the .css file correctly (i.e. click on the link in view source and check it actually takes you there and isn't a broken link)

Comment: I checked it and found that it was not a broken link.

Comment: I have somehow managed to get the color change done, but the font change is still not happening

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `@font-face` and import the file. The css allready uses font-face. Try:

```
@import url("http://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/lohitdevanagari.css");
body 
{

}
.txtQues
{
    font-family: 'Lohit Devanagari',serif;   
    font-size:14px;
    background-color:Yellow;
}
```

Comment: I can't seem to get it to work.. I made a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/7trE4/1/

Answer (score 0):

In the below code remove "EnableTheming" or make it false.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtQuestion" runat="server" Height="101px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="627px" meta:resourcekey="txtQuestionResource1"  EnableTheming="True" ontextchanged="txtQuestion_TextChanged" CssClass="txtQues"></asp:TextBox>
```

Also try to keep important for your styles in CSS like below.

```
.txtQues
{
font-family: 'Lohit Devanagari',serif !important;   
font-size:14px !important;
background-color:Yellow !important;
}
```

Comment: Well @Suresh, do I need to keep the enable theming true or false

Comment: make enabletheming to false or get rid of that.

Comment: Still the same result @Suresh

Comment: :) we need to see your original code. Give the site url or reproduce the same in jsfiddle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56269/discussion-between-tvicky-and-suresh-ponnukalai).